# Having issues with rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, rake

I am running Rails 3.1.1 and getting this error when running this command. Obviously new to Rails, any help appreciated:

rake aborted!
undefined method `prerequisites' for nil:NilClass

```
/Users/220040168/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-rails-2.6.0/lib/rspec/rails/tasks/rspec.rake:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/220040168/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-rails-2.6.0/lib/rspec-rails.rb:10:in `load'
/Users/220040168/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-rails-2.6.0/lib/rspec-rails.rb:10:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/Users/220040168/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:183:in `call'
/Users/220040168/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:183:in `block in load_tasks'
/Users/220040168/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:183:in `each'
/Users/220040168/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:183:in `load_tasks'
/Users/220040168/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:396:in `block in load_tasks'
/Users/220040168/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `each'
/Users/220040168/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `all'
/Users/220040168/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:396:in `load_tasks'
/Users/220040168/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `load_tasks'
/Users/220040168/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/Users/220040168/rails_projects/sample_app/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/220040168/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/Users/220040168/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/220040168/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:501:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/220040168/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Users/220040168/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/220040168/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:81:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/220040168/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:65:in `block in run'
/Users/220040168/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/220040168/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Users/220040168/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/220040168/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/220040168/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

Not the first time I have run this command, but first time I am getting this error.

GEMFILE

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'

group :development do
    gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.0'
end

group :test do
    gem 'rspec', '2.6.0'
    gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
    gem 'autotest', '4.3.2'
    gem 'autotest-rails-pure', '4.1.0'
    gem 'autotest-fsevent', '0.2.2'
    gem 'autotest-growl', '0.2.4'
end


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

Comment: Rails version? Stack trace? Also, search your project for prerequisites and see if there is anything that calls this method.

Comment: Please add it all to your answer.

Comment: Plus a Gemfile might help, I've had similar errors because of Gem dependencies.

Comment: Added gemfile to the question

Comment: Could you please show us a stacktrace (use `--trace`), that will hopefully show the line where the occurs. From the top of my head: something is calling `prerequisites` on a object that is not there. E.g. missing configuration? We need more info to be of any kind of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks related to this issue https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1197
Try to upgrade to a newer rspec-rails version than 2.6.0

Comment: That solved it...I had to reinstall and update my gemlock file to get the update to take. Any pointers going forward on managing my gem versions? And thank you for the help!!